# Patch method not allowed! is there an alternative request method?

Tags: laravel, methods, request, axios, patch

I keep getting this error

**Error**

**PATCH http://localhost/cart/027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

I read somewhere that patch method is not enable on the server, I am using Apache 2.4.41 I tried to find a way to enable it through the mod_allowmethods  module but the file can't be edited or modify. At this point I am stuck any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code trying to update the cart quantity

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <select class="quantity" data-id= "{{ $item->rowId }}">
          <option value="">1</option>
          <option value="">2</option>
          <option value="">3</option>
          <option value="">4</option>
          <option value="">5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>
    (function(){
        const classname = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')

        Array.from(classname).forEach(function(element) {

          element.addEventListener('change', function() {

            const id = element.getAttribute('data-id')

            axios.patch(`/cart/${id}`, {

              quantity: this.value
            })
            .then(function(response) {

              windows.location.href = '{{ route('cart.index') }}'
            })

            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
          })

        })
    })();
</script>
```

**The Route**

```
Route::patch('/cart/{product}', 'CartController@update')->name('cart.update');
```

**The CartController**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Cart::update($id, $request->quantity);

    session()->flash('success', 'Quantity was updated successfully');
    
    return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

Comment: Two possibilities. 1) You are caching your routes and updated it to patch since it was last cached. You can try ```php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear```. 2) Your nginx/apache config is blocking the patch method. Look through your config and see if it is being blocked anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I tried clearing the route cache and config cache is still the same error, the apache config doesn't have any settings blocking it only link to the modules which I believe the mod_allowmethods module has the settings but can't be edited, is a .SO file type.

Comment: Well the code you have posted looks fine to me. This is likely an apache issue.

Answer (score 0):

use post method and send patch as data.

```
axios.post('/cart/${id}', {
    quantity: this.value,
    _method: 'patch',
    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' 
})
.then(function(response) {
    windows.location.href = '{{ route('cart.index') }}'
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: thank you for responding, but i get this error after trying this code                                   
  POST http://localhost/cart/8a48aa7c8e5202841ddaf767bb4d10da 404 (Not Found)

Comment: did you add  `_method: 'patch'` ??

Comment: Yeah I did, exactly as you posted.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
add csrf-token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and remove "/" : `/cart/${id}`

```
axios.patch(`cart/${id}`, {
                quantity : this.value
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```